# sorting stack bar chart in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using a stacked bar chart for presenting the gender ratio in various region.
here the legend is gender and Axis is region and value is headcount.
when i want to sort the chart according to female gender value . the sorting is only done by the headcount value. how can i sort it for the percentage value. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: My first answer focused only on count, now I've taken into account that OP wants to sort by percentage female value**

---

You can sort your data directly in your `Stacked column chart` visualization, after `pivoting the data` and `adding a column` showing the female percentage value using the `Power Query Editor`. If you insert the female ratio as a `Tooltip`, your chart can be sorted as that value even though it is not displayed in your chart.

Here are the details:

---

This data sample should fit your description:

```
Region,Gender,Count
USA,M,9000
USA,F,7000
EU,M,5000
EU,F,5000
UK,M,2000
UK,F,4000
CAN,M,100
CAN,F,900
```

If you enter that data using Edit Queries / the Power Query Editor, you can set it up like this:

[image]

Now highlight the Gender column, and select Transform > Pivot Column to get this:

[image]

Under `Values Column`, select `Count` and click `OK` to get this:

[image]

Now simpy add a custom column to calgulate the female ratio like so:

[image]

Now your table should look like this:

[image]

In the desktop, insert a stacked column chart and set it up like below. Notice that you'll need to insert `F ratio` under `Tooltips`:

[image]

Now you can sort your chart by `Ascending` or `Descending F ratio`

[image]