# Sort visualization data using a column not displayed

Tags: powerbi

This may look like a rookie question but in PowerBI, is it possible to

1. Not sort the data in a visualization (keep the natural order from the query)
2. If the answer to 1 is no, sort the data using a column that is not displayed in the visualization (for instance, sort table rows by an index that is not displayed in the table)

I found a workaround for charts (using the sort column as tooltip, the sort column becomes available in the available sorting columns) but I didn't for tables.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You can insert any column under `Tooltips` and it will be available for sorting in the same toolbar as in the screenshot below. Take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424336/sorting-stack-bar-chart-in-power-bi/52439049#52439049) for further details.

---

Regarding:

> 1. Not sort the data in a visualization (keep the natural order from the
>      query)

I recently had problems with categorical data being sorted in a Visualization in a useless way, and *not* in the same way as in the query (or table in Power Query Editor). And If I'm not missing the point completely, you should be able to sort your data as you like by clicking the three dots in the top right of your visualization:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately you can only select fields taking part into the viz :(

Comment: Take a look at my recent edit in the answer and see if that solves it for you.

Comment: Thanks but it's the 'hack' I mentioned in my question. I'm looking for a more robust solution + this does not work for tables.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I honestly did not see that part. I'm inclined to delete my answer.